# Rewriting an Infinite Sum as an Infinite Sum of Finite Sums

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say I have the sequence
$$\{a_{n}\}=f(1),f(2),f(3),\quad f(5),f(6),f(7),\quad f(9),\dots$$
As you can see we have $f(n)$ but it skips an every $4n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume $f(n)>0$. I then want to consider
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$
and specifically I want to know if I can write
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=4n+1}^{4(n+1)-1}f(j)\right)$$
i.e. sum up the sums of the "chunks". My general intuition would say yes, but my mathematical intuition raises some red flags just knowing how careful we must be with infinite sums. I am especially worried because since I have defined $f(n)>0$, if we let the summand on the right hand side be $b_{n+1}$ then we have that $a_n<b_n$ for all $n$ that we sum over. So at this point I would believe that I cannot do this, in which case is there any way to get this separation of chunks in some way shape or form, and if not can I write the sum of $a_n$ explicitly (as an easy to work with function, i.e. not a bunch of mods or floors etc...)?

Comment: There might be a cleaner way to write your sum, although there is no problem with it as long as convergence occurs on the LHS. Can you find a better relationship between $n$ and $k$, where $a_n=f(k)$? I think you can, in which case you need not bother looking into these kind of loopholes.

Comment: Not an answer to the actual question, but possibly related: if both $\sum_{n \ge 1} f(n)$ and $\sum_{n \ge 1} f(4 n)$ converge then $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n$ will converge to the difference of their limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the definition for what it means for an infinite sum to have some value then you should understand that you can group adjacent terms together as you will still get (a subset of) the same partial sums. In general you can reorder the terms of an infinite sum as you like and get the same result only if it is absolutely convergent.